# Template literal type for Object key paths

Tags: typescript

I am reading about template literal types in tyepscript and found [this](https://github.com/ghoullier/awesome-template-literal-types?tab=readme-ov-file#dot-notation-string-type-safe) type which generates all possible object key paths.
[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40336-88#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgQxACwJIFsIBsA8AVAGhgGkowYoAPEKAOwBMBnGAazIHsAzGPAPhgC8wGCTIVqdJjEYgATgEtaAc2EwA-DwDapMAF1xNBswBKUAMbtZ9HDIXKiCWmF6qRGgD4wABgBIA3joAvgB0-ogoGNj42mS6RACilGZYAK70UDhsYFxaOnGsHNyOYJq6vPwAZNJyikqBXq4iMJ6+AWQh-onJaRlZOXgxekR9RU6lldV2dQ1NMABcMLRQAG5QsqoLS6uyANzAoJCw4WiYWABM+PwC8EgnUYQF2dx8zY-9ewfQNyiXgt9351+VEMUlstVeIx46n+kUBLwWkLwH3AX2OADUEKkMg84AZJMxjpcrqpccD8d5-IpOGtRGAOn4qTTTDJ6qoNDo8UY3s9GhpmSBOVJCQM8i5Zm5-hisdE8kR+WLxZsVmtGkrtht4ILmIjeVo4LpVYtlbt9ulkghZLBOClaGYQPJ2LQYEooCB8ERSRIucLygAKdgAIwAVgsHhBbgs4ABKSO3KUpbEe3gfCy0GQwQNB8wC65+VSceSyGQAOQQ6CgCwARAAReRQJTsSsEVRYBAlssVmCVgASCAAXk3VAgXQsAMwABmbIggsnYWbtjAWmkafkWHarpgQLHkICbMFTNQDKRAlkXMAAbAAOGCBKdNVe0dddgDCjpkSCge4PCiPJ6LCwARjOG87wNQIYDbfc3xAD4XRAf1g2zIhKxnOds0YYJKyjHYgA) from the original tweet.

```
type PathImpl<T, Key extends keyof T> =
  Key extends string
  ? T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
    ? | `${Key}.${PathImpl<T[Key], Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]>> & string}`
      | `${Key}.${Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]> & string}`
    : never
  : never;

type PathImpl2<T> = PathImpl<T, keyof T> | keyof T;

type Path<T> = PathImpl2<T> extends string | keyof T ? PathImpl2<T> : keyof T;
```

In the type PathImpl, `Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]>` is used. According to my understanding,  `keyof any[]` should include all the methods which are present in Array as well as the indices like 0,1,2,3... . So when we exclude `keyof any[]` from `keyof T[Key]`, it should remove indices also from the keys of `T[Key]`. But that does not seem to happen here. What am I missing here?

Comment: ① Welcome to SO. Please [edit] to put any code you want us to look at as plain text in the question itself.  A Playground link is nice but it' doesn't suffice. ② Tuple types get numeric-*like* string-valued keys such as `"0"` and `"1`", corresponding to known-present element positions.  But `any[]` does *not* have that.  `keyof any[]` contains `number`, but `"0"` is not a `number`.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (after you [edit] to make the question conform to SO rules). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, Yes it answers my question. I will edit the question to include code. Thanks

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance. It might not be for a number of hours because it's my bedtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine the keys of [the `Array` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) using [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator):

```
type KeyofArray = {} & keyof any[];
// type KeyofArray = number | typeof Symbol.iterator | typeof Symbol.unscopables | 
//   "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" | "concat" | "join" | 
//   "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort" | "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf" | 
//   "lastIndexOf" | "every" | "some" | "forEach" | "map" | "filter" | "reduce" | 
//   "reduceRight" | "find" | "findIndex" | "fill" | "copyWithin" | "entries" | 
//   "keys" | "values" | "includes"
```

(The [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with the empty object type `{}` doesn't change the resulting type, but it does prompt the compiler to expand the definition instead of leaving it in terms of `keyof`.)

Let's compare that to the keys of a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) such as the three-element tuple `["a", "b", "c"]`:

```
type KeyofTuple = {} & keyof ["a", "b", "c"];
// type KeyofTuple = number | typeof Symbol.iterator | typeof Symbol.unscopables | 
//   "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" | "concat" | "join" | 
//   "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort" | "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf" | 
//   "lastIndexOf" | "every" | "some" | "forEach" | "map" | "filter" | "reduce" | 
//   "reduceRight" | "find" | "findIndex" | "fill" | "copyWithin" | "entries" | 
//   "keys" | "values" | "includes" | "0" | "1" | "2"
```

You can see that tuple types contain all the same keys as array types, but they *also* include specific indices that are known to exist due to the tuple's length.  For a tuple of length 3, this is `"0" | "1" | "2"`, which can be demonstrated using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers):

```
type Diff = Exclude<KeyofTuple, KeyofArray>;
// type Diff = "0" | "1" | "2"
```

It's important to notice that these indices are *string* [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and not *numeric* literal types.  Keys of objects in JavaScript are always either strings or symbols, never numbers. Numeric keys get coerced to strings, and so the presence of `number` as an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) key is a convenient fiction that TypeScript supports in order to let people use numbers as keys.

Because `"0" | "1" | "2"` aren't number literal types, then `Exclude<KeyofTuple, KeyofArray>` doesn't eliminate them.  In an alternate world, the language designers could have decided to include `0 | 1 | 2` instead of `"0" | "1" | "2"` (and I can't easily locate documentation that explains why they didn't do this). If they had, then `Diff` above would be `never` because `0 | 1 | 2` is a subtype of `number`, and `number` is part of `KeyofArray`.  You'd still be able to tease `0 | 1 | 2` out of the type definition, but it would be significantly more work than just `Exclude`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHsBmBBATmghiKBeKA3gL5QBkUA1vMlJgHYgDaAugNwCwAUAPTdSiRY1VBmx4odAK4BbAEYQ0UAD79wEGgGUQchABsAdAEtgCzMASKVA9UihadByXQDOAYwRhMs3RGfKoXLxQwQBEPnQA5sAAFiH+IeYawGiGkXEqCQgAMgiumD5JKWnxYB7pUCFgks6x8e50ecDlIQBWCKnlgXyhaBAAbgrOEM01hkhN8c66hq7DkxYTGc5g07PNTqPjzakAJhAAHgDySJ083RW6mM7AAJJ0e0cn8f0KICMI0nMZSBYAopiuWoZaSYMDNJCGXQmNDNXo7SRrfxdYIVOEIiAAJUMEWiiwqEPu4N2dweRN0uma7jAIAA6sZoh1nnRkoZfKcgqEqCBnM0+vlJGz4qlXLpJHseVwuNYhIgkAAVSQraD4YhkSjCKCMEKYEIAGgqsj1FVcITYyOlcFlCqV4ikcgU-msmm0sj0RmhZgsjrUzoc+g2VK8Pj8KmRoXCUSBFUSLOKGXMOTyBVjEWapTBJWqUZC9UazTajNDZxRIV6AzQQxGDK2k1WXwqzgWIxWM3rIQ21bxIV2B2O7POYSut3uvaeGReaDe80+4L+AOzIIz30h0NhEHhiKLHNR6-RWJxXYJOyJ9xJBzJFLqHlp9MLFQgzJSgq3A65PPifNFz4qwtF4uaAAMzQAIzNAATCEkqcNKAAiYy2Pgvz7CKYoQAAPJayDWj4+qYSIWAgAAfBwxawfB4ghEB8SgfEEFcEAA)